# How to log into a user account page upon storing login data in session storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, components

I am building a simple login system in React and I am attempting to allow a user to input an email and password to log in, only after this log in data is saved to session storage. The email and password are successfully stored in session storage, but the page does not refresh & subsequent return {} function in my-account.js does not render.

My understanding of how this code works:

- the 'useToken()' hook contains a state object with the function 'getToken()' and the state variable 'token', with a state determined by 'useState(getToken())' - which will set the state of 'token' to the session storage variable named 'token'.
- useToken() is imported into my-account.js and 'token' and 'setToken()' are both destructured from the parent function, retrieving the correct data in the my-account component.

The 'useToken()' function does not set 'token' and it returns a null, when it should be returning the token that is successfully stored in session storage. I would appreciate any help with this one.

```
//my-account.js

import React from 'react';
import Login from "../components/login"
import useToken from "../hooks/useToken"


const MyAccount = () =>{

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{token.email ? `Logged in as ${token.email}` : 'Not logged in'}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyAccount;
```

```
//useToken.js

import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = (userToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken);
  };
  
  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token,
  }
}
```

```
//login.js

const Login = ({setToken}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLoggingIn, setIsLoggingIn] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
  Login.propTypes = {
    setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoggingIn(true);
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users", { email, password });
      console.log(data);

      const user = data.find(
        (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
      );
      if (user) {
        console.log("user is found");

        // set token to store pass as a prop to store login data in local memory
        var token = user;
        console.log(token);
        setToken(token);

        setError(false);
        setIsLoggingIn(false);

      } else {
        setError(new Error("Incorrect email or password"));
        setIsLoggingIn(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setIsLoggingIn(false);
    }
  };

  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-container">
      {error && <div className="error">{error.message}</div>}
      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <>
        <button className="fancyButton defaultBtn" type="submit" disabled={isLoggingIn}>
          {isLoggingIn ? 'Logging in...' : 'Log In'}
        </button>
      </>
      <p>If you do not have an account, register <Link to="/register">here</Link></p>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in `<Login>`

I made a local copy and it worked just fine. Here is my Login.js

```
function Login({ setToken }) {
    setToken("test");
    return <div></div>;
}

export default Login;
```